# Show that it is possible to express the complete solution without squares knowing three particular solutions for the edo

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Show that it is possible to express the complete solution without squares knowing three particular solutions $y=y_1(x),y=y_2(x),y=y_3(x)$ for the edo
$$y'+Py^2+Qy+R=0$$

Comment: Can you sketch how the proof you know proceeds? What exactly is unclear, the motivation for using some construction, some steps in it, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there is a relationship between the quadruple quotient of the solutions equal to a constant. But I don't get the formal demonstration.
$$\frac{y-y_1}{y-y_2}\frac{y_3-y_2}{y_3-y_1}=C$$

Comment: Please use answers only for answers. For clarifications on your state of knowledge and its breaking point please extend the question by [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4313195/edit)ing it.

Comment: @Santiago Seeker: you can take derivative of left side and use $y_1'=-Py_1^2-Qy_1-R$ etc. to exclude derivatives of $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$, $y$. You should get zero.

Answer (score 0):

By inspiration from linear DE and binomial formulas, you get for any two solutions
$$
\frac{y_j'-y_k'}{y_j-y_k}=-P(y_j+y_k)-Q\tag{jk}
$$
Now one can get $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4$ on the right side after the factor $P$ by using three different pairings of the indices. Subtracting two of the variants gives
$$
\frac{y_1'-y_3'}{y_1-y_3}+\frac{y_2'-y_4'}{y_2-y_4}
-\frac{y_1'-y_4'}{y_1-y_4}-\frac{y_2'-y_3'}{y_2-y_3}
=0
$$
Integrating these logarithmic derivatives and exponentiating gives the stated identity between the solutions, with $y=y_4$.